# Unix - Return first and last row of a similar value

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a table like this:

```
1000    2000    Ally  
1001    2001    Ally  
1002    2002    Ally  
1003    2003    Ally  
2000    4000    Kate  
2010    4010    Kate  
2020    4020    Kate  
3000    9000    Lisa
```

I would like for it to return the first and the last line when the 3rd column has the same value. In this case it would return:

```
1000    2000    Ally  
1003    2003    Ally  
2000 4000 Kate  
2020 4020 Kate  
3000    9000    Lisa
```

Anyway of using `awk`/`sed`/`grep` to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

with awk

```
NR == 1   {first=last=$0; key=$3 }
$3 == key {last=$0}
$3 != key {print first; if(first != last) print last; 
           first=last=$0; key=$3}
END       {print first; if(first != last) print last}
```

works for me on your dataset

not tested on anything else

Per @James-Brown's requests in the comments 
a version which prints dups

```
NR ==1    {print; key=$3 }
$3 == key {last=$0}
$3 != key {print last "\n" $0; key=$3}
END       {print last}
```

(probably does something else wrong for other data)

Comment: If `Lisa` is there twice, it only gets printed once.

Comment: on my system you are incorrect. if Lisa is there twice (with different row values) Lisa is printed twice

Comment: My bad, I should've stated _with same values_. I shouldn't do this before breakfast...

Comment: no worries when the Lisa rows were completely identical you would be correct

Comment: which `that` are we up to?   OP may not have known how to give a proper spec but i will guess you could.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this simple `awk` 1-liner to print 1st and last records for each distinct value of 3rd column:

```
awk '!arr[$3] {arr[$3]=$0; if(prevline) print prevline; print} {prevline=$0}' file
```

Associative arrays are a big help in this case.

Sample run:

```
$ cat file 
1000    2000    Ally  
1001    2001    Ally  
1002    2002    Ally  
1003    2003    Ally  
2000    4000    Kate  
2010    4010    Kate  
2020    4020    Kate  
3000    9000    Lisa
$ awk '!arr[$3] {arr[$3]=$0; if(prevline) print prevline; print} {prevline=$0}' file
1000    2000    Ally  
1003    2003    Ally  
2000    4000    Kate  
2020    4020    Kate  
3000    9000    Lisa
```

Comment: If there's a value that only occurs once in the middle of the list, it will print twice.

Comment: If the first record key (Ally) exist only once, it gets printed twice. If the last record key (Lisa) exists more than once, it only gets printed once.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with anything clever, they all seemed to fail one way or other. I blame TGIF but let's go with this one:

```
$ awk '{
           if($3 in first)
               last[$3]=$0; 
           else 
               first[$3]=$0
       } 
       END {
           for(i in first) 
               print first[i] ((i in last)?ORS last[i]:"")
       }' file # | sort -k3 -k1
2000    4000    Kate
2020    4020    Kate
3000    9000    Lisa
1000    2000    Ally
1003    2003    Ally
```

Downside is that the order won't be the same as in the original file but that can be saved with `sort`. Upside is that the matching records don't have to be next to each other in the source file.